# Simple-navigation: undefined local variable or method `root'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I installed and configured simple-navigation as decribed [here (simple-navigation configuration)](https://github.com/codeplant/simple-navigation/wiki/Configuration).

I modified **config/navigation.rb** (contains only one menu item):

```
primary.item :key_1, 'Home', root
```

My **config/routes.rb** contains:

```
root 'static_pages#home'
```

**rake routes** contains string:

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern  Controller#Action
    root    GET   /            static_pages#home
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb** contains:

```
<%= render "layouts/header" %>
```

**app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb** contains:

```
<%= render "layouts/main_nav" %>
```

and **app/views/layouts/_main_nav.html.erb** contains one string:

```
<%= render_navigation %>
```

After that I got an error:

```
Showing <...>_main_nav.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined local variable or method `root'
```

Why restful route helpers and named route helpers are "invisible" in this case? I tried all of the prefixes from the routes table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd argument should be an URL or path, so change `root` to `root_path` in **config/navigation.rb**. Your menu item should look like:

```
primary.item :key_1, 'Home', root_path
```